# Mysql client called with `docker-compose run` vs. `docker-compose exec`

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Why do you need to specify a host when calling with `docker-compose run`?

e.g.

`docker-compose run db_container mysql -uuser -ppass db_name -h db_container`

seems to be the direct equivalent of

`docker-compose exec db_container mysql -uuser -ppass db_name`

When omitting the hostname flag from the first example, mysql fails with a "can't connect to socket" error.

What is the difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

docker-compose run will start a new container on the same network with a name like `folder_db_container_run_1`. This is not running mysql since you passed it a command. So it is running that command. So you connect from this container to the original db container

```
docker-compose run db_container mysql -uuser -ppass db_name -h db_container
```

While when you do exec you get inside the running container. And not specifying host means local mysql

```
docker-compose exec db_container mysql -uuser -ppass db_name
```

That is why it works. No extra container is launched in this case

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. If you have time, could you please point me to the relevant passage in the docs? I just read the entry for `docker-compose run` and i don't think that's made clear.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/. `Commands you use with run start in new containers with configuration defined by that of the service, including volumes, links, and other details. However, there are two important differences.`