# docker-compose up versus docker-compose run, why the latter seems not to start the services?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```sh
version: '3.8'
services:
   db:
      image: postgres:12-alpine
      environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=tester
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=atest
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
      ports:
      - 5432:5432
      expose:
      - 5432
```

Doing:

```sh
> docker-compose up -d
...
> psql test_db -U tester -h localhost
Password for user tester:
psql (12.3)
Type "help" for help.

test_db=# \l
                              List of databases
   Name    | Owner  | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | Access privileges
-----------+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------
 postgres  | tester | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | tester | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/tester        +
           |        |          |            |            | tester=CTc/tester
 template1 | tester | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/tester        +
           |        |          |            |            | tester=CTc/tester
 test_db   | tester | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
(4 rows)
\q
```

```sh
> docker-compose exec db ps awx
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 postgres  0:00 postgres
   46 postgres  0:00 postgres: checkpointer
   47 postgres  0:00 postgres: background writer
   48 postgres  0:00 postgres: walwriter
   49 postgres  0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher
   50 postgres  0:00 postgres: stats collector
   51 postgres  0:00 postgres: logical replication launcher
   52 root      0:00 ps awx
```

works fine. Same if doing:

```sh
docker-compose exec db psql test_db -U tester
```

That's pretty fine too.

**However**, doing as follow:

```sh
> docker-compose down

> docker-compose run db psql test_db -U tester
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
failed to resize tty, using default size

> docker-compose run db /bin/sh
/ # ps awx
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh
    7 root      0:00 ps awx
```

So I can see that using `docker-compose run db` the `postgres service` is not being started. **Why**?

What

```sh
    --entrypoint CMD      Override the entrypoint of the image.
```

in `docker-compose run --help` does really mean? If there's something to be overridden than it means the entrypoint should be being executed, shouldn't be?

**UPDATE**
I've checked https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/, considering whether `--service-ports` would do any help, which it didn't (not surprised, as I emphasized above, `postgres` service is not started, so I don't see how it could be a ports issue), and found even an example:

`docker-compose run db psql -h db -U docker`

But alas! this is precisely what I'm trying to do for no avail!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Port Publishing When Running with Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320172/port-publishing-when-running-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Unfortunately no. See my update above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please see this answer:  [Mysql client called with `docker-compose run` vs. `docker-compose exec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223409/mysql-client-called-with-docker-compose-run-vs-docker-compose-exec)

When you do `docker-compose run`, it creates a new instance of `db` separate from the configuration in your `docker-compose.yml`.

The best way to see what is happening is to run `docker-compose up`, then from another shell run `docker-compose exec db bash`, then from another shell run `docker-compose run db bash`.

If you look at the output of `hostname` and `ifconfig`, you will see that `exec` connects you to the existing `db` while `run` puts you into a new one.

In response to OP's linking [this article](https://medium.com/@zhao.li/how-to-understand-the-difference-between-docker-composes-up-vs-run-vs-exec-commands-a506151967df), I should have emphasized earlier that though there is nothing wrong with running PostgreSQL under Docker, running a database is counter to the general container ethos of statelessness.  In the context of a stateful and persistent container like a database, the `docker-compose run` command seems to make no sense.

Comment: Indeed, only when I specified the db_host that the command worked:
`docker-compose run db psql -d test_db -U tester -h host.docker.internal` and docker must be up.

Comment: Yet, it's still frustrating that I need to start all my services when I just want to test DB. Frankly, I see no point in `docker-compose run` when compared with `docker-compose exec`.

Comment: Now I understand the diff between `docker-compose run` and `docker-compose exec`, see [here](https://medium.com/@zhao.li/how-to-understand-the-difference-between-docker-composes-up-vs-run-vs-exec-commands-a506151967df).

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is, `docker-compose run` just runs one-time command to your service. It overwrite previous commands in your configuration. Here i think it overwrote the command that start postgres service in your container.

(Last line)
https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/1d140375b6830c65cfeaac3642c7fda6d3e1b29a/12/alpine/Dockerfile

In your case, because you ran `docker-compose down` first so when you run `docker-compose run db psql test_db -U tester` your service did not run command to start posgres first instead of running your NEW COMMANDS `psql ...`. You can test that every normal command like `ls, pwd, ...` run well with `docker-compose run` instead of `psql`.

If you dont run `docker-compose down`, everthing works properly with `docker-compose run db psql test_db -U tester -h db` .

Comment: Actually, with docker up and `docker-compose run db psql -d test_db -U tester -h host.docker.internal` it did work.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a very useful article on ENTRYPOINT vs CMD
https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Entrypoint is a command or script that is run every time you run the container and can't be overwritten. CMD can be replaced by arguments in the docker-compose, ENTRYPOINT can't.

Comment: Please add all information to your answer instead of linking to external ressources - and how does this answer the main question about why the second command does not work as expected?